# How to copy image from windows file system to winrt(metro) c#/xaml

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

My program wants to copy a file from the windows file system that the user may have of their client already and replace an existing image which is a thumbnail/profileimage in the app.

to save the new image over the old Im doing this:

```
async private void saveImage(string name, int clientId)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfileImages", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        try
        {

            StorageFile newFileImage = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(photoImageStoragePath);

            StorageFile originalFileImage = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(originalPhotoImageStoragePath);
            await newFileImage.CopyAndReplaceAsync(originalFileImage);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            var name2 = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", name, GenerateId(), ".png");                
            copyImageAsync(folder, name2, clientId);
        }


    }
```

so the original image is being replaced by the new image. I am creating new storage files for each based on there path, I made sure all my previously used filestreams are .disposed() so Im a little lost as to why I keep getting access denied. I get it if I use copyandreplace and if i used moveandreplace.

The exact error code is System.UnauthorizedAccess - {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}

Comment: How do you get `originalPhotoImageStoragePath`? What is its value? Your app might not have permission to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer lies in what happened after the save, in the windows 8 metro app the save was kicked off and the screen was transitioned to another screen which listed all the clients again:

because async/await is kicking in and the process of saving the image has been kicked off to a task, the save method has been given a promise of job completion and the process is kicked back up to the UI transitioning to a new screen, on that new screen the request for the image is made again for displaying the client data in a list. That task to retrieve looks to have been given priority and its locking the old image for display before the save task has a chance to finish writing the new image to the file.

So what Im looking at doing is having a in memory collection of the objects that have images. When a CRUD operation has been kicked off by a page, the page will call a [REPOSITORY](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) for that TYPE and the repo will update the in memory collection and also write to the file. This will allow me to have the pages pull their data from the in memory collection rather than the individual file that may or may not have been updated because they have been pushed off to background processes/tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432876/Windows-8-The-Right-Way-to-Read-Write-Files-in-Win) link suggest it is maybe one capabilities option to enable. Look at the "Read Local files w/o a Picker" part it explains how to enable the Documents Library Access.

Be aware of :

> I might take a moment to talk about StorageFolder, too. One of the
> most common requests I get is to iterate files and folders on user’s
> system. You really can’t – if what you mean is to start at c:. Try to
> iterate through c:\ and you get this: [EXCEPTION] You can, however,
> iterate the files in a Library (Documents, Photos, Music, Videos, and
> even Home Group)  folder – if you have requested this capability in
> the manifest. It is important to note that the files returned for a
> folder will be automatically filtered to the file types you declare in
> your manifest. (Did I already mention *.* cannot be declared?) Let me
> restate that as a developer you have intentional restrictions like
> this that ultimately improve the user’s experience and safety.

Regards

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I actually had read that already. But what i did just find out. Is because async await is kicking in and the process of saving the image has been kicked off to a task, the save method has been given a promise of job completion and the process is kicked back up to the UI transitioning to a new screen, on that new screen the request for the image is made again for displaying the client data in a list. That task to retrieve looks to have been given priority and its locking the old image for display before the save task has a chance to finish writing the new image to the file.

Comment: So what Im looking at doing is having a in memory collection of the objects that have images. When a CRUD operation has been kicked off by a page, the page will call a repository for that TYPE and the repo will update the in memory collection and also write to the file. 

This will allow me to have the pages pull there data from the in memory collection rather than the individual file that may or may not have been updated because they have been pushed off to background processes/tasks.